# Error using QueryDSL sorting with Hibernate Search module

Tags: java, lucene, querydsl, hibernate-search

In my repository class, I'm trying make a query using querydsl-hibernate-search module, version 4.1.4, together with Spring Data JPA, version 1.5.2. When I call the method:

```
public Iterable<Incident> findAll(Predicate predicate, int offset, int limit, OrderSpecifier<?>[] orders) {
    return createQuery(predicate).orderBy(orders).offset(offset).limit(limit).fetch();
}
```

That call:

```
private SearchQuery<Incident> createQuery(Predicate predicate) {
    return new SearchQuery<>(getEntityManager().unwrap(HibernateEntityManager.class).getSession(), incident).where(predicate);
}
```

I got this error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.lucene.search.SortField.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;IZ)V
```

Looking inside of code sources, I found the problem, a method on class: LuceneSerializer, line: 557:

```
public Sort toSort(List<? extends OrderSpecifier<?>> orderBys) {
    List<SortField> sorts = new ArrayList<SortField>(orderBys.size());
    for (OrderSpecifier<?> order : orderBys) {
        if (!(order.getTarget() instanceof Path<?>)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("argument was not of type Path.");
        }
        Class<?> type = order.getTarget().getType();
        boolean reverse = !order.isAscending();
        Path<?> path = getPath(order.getTarget());
        if (Number.class.isAssignableFrom(type)) {
            sorts.add(new SortField(toField(path), sortFields.get(type), reverse));
        } else {
            sorts.add(new SortField(toField(path), sortLocale, reverse));
        }
    }
    Sort sort = new Sort();
    sort.setSort(sorts.toArray(new SortField[sorts.size()]));
    return sort;
}
```

The constructor method of class SortField has incorrect parameters:

```
sorts.add(new SortField(toField(path), sortFields.get(type), reverse));
```

It seems to me it's a version conflict issue between querydsl-hibernate-seach and lucene.

Comment: It certainly does look like a version conflict. Which versions of Lucene and Hibernate Search are you using?

Comment: Suggestion: don't expect that you can take any two libraries and that they will work together. You need to pick them in specific combinations so that versions align. Ideally a complete version alignment but since that's often not practical at least try to match the major/minor versions. In this case check the Apache Lucene versions used by your choice of Hibernate Search, but you will also want to check for Hibernate ORM compatibility with your choice of Spring Data.

Comment: spring-boot-starter version: 1.5.2.RELEASE, hibernate-search-orm - version: 5.5.6.Final and querydsl-hibernate-search version: 4.1.4

Comment: @YoannRodière I found a config property: spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.search.lucene_version that can be put on application.properties file, but I don't know what value is more suitable...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can see [here](https://github.com/querydsl/querydsl/blob/master/querydsl-hibernate-search/pom.xml), `querydsl-hibernate-search` depends on an ancient version of Hibernate Search (4.2.0.Final). I wouldn't expect it to work with Hibernate Search 5.5.6.

A lot of things have been going on since 4.2.0.Final, so I think you only have two options:

- Contribute to `querydsl-hibernate-search` to upgrade it to the latest version of Hibernate Search
- Don't use `querydsl-hibernate-search` and use the [built-in query DSL in Hibernate Search](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.5/reference/en-US/html_single/#search-query-querydsl)

You could use `querydsl-hibernate-search` as is, but it would force you to use a really old version of Hibernate Search ([not even on the migration guide anymore](http://hibernate.org/search/documentation/migrate/)) which will incidentally force you to use an old version of Hibernate ORM, and so on...

Comment: Thank you for your response. I agree with you. I recently opened an issue regarding this problem.